# Matrix inequality proof from Munkres' analysis text

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Why is this theorem true?

> If matrix $A$ has size $n$ by $m$ and matrix $B$ has size $m$ by $p$ then
>
> $$|A\cdot B|\leq m|A||B|$$

I found that somebody already provided this proof at the link below so don't bother writing an answer here.
[Linear Algebra munkres analysis on manifolds question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263942/linear-algebra-munkres-analysis-on-manifolds-question?rq=1)

Comment: What is the number $|A|$?

Comment: Is $| \cdot |$ a matrix norm?

Comment: It is the sup norm